# Как сделать HTTP запрос в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, веб-сервер

**Описание**:
Имеем форму ввода с одним текстовым полем.
Введя в поле некий номер, нажимаем submit.

Должен выполниться http запрос на внешний api сервис.
Где запрашиваются данные по фильтру, написанному в поле ввода.

Для этой реализации нужно:

1. Метод `search` в контроллере (это будет отображение страницы с полем ввода). `Submit` ведет на метод `searching` в том же контроллере.

**Вопрос**:
Как мне сделать вызов внешнего API?
А именно:

1. Где создать файл с классом и методами для вызова API и парсинга?
2. Как файл подключить в контроллер для создания объекта и вызова метода?
3. Получив данные, как их передать в представление?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно под это пишется `ServiceObject` - простой рубишный класс с методом `call`, который на вход принимает данные из формы, идёт с ними в апишку, парсит ответ и что-то нужное возвращает. Эти все действия аккуратно раскладываются по приватным методам, конечно же.

Соответственно, в контроллере просто вызываете `MySearchApiClient.new.call(query: params[:query])`, результат складываете в @переменную и пользуете её во вьюшке

Comment: Понял.А где создать файл с классом и как его подключить?

Comment: app/services/my_search_api_client.rb Автоматически подгрузится, как и всё, что живёт в app